# Make links in a specific div open in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to open links in my post on a new page or a new tab rather. But only the link in the specific division, not all the links on my page. I don't wanna put _blank in all my tags it's too time consuming. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ayush specific division means?? you mean certain links. please let me know if they are a href or div clicks.There are multiple ways to do that.

Comment: @ayush , if the answer given by others fixes your problem mark that as answer.So that they will respond fast in future for the questions and help everyone.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With jQuery, you could set the `target` to `_blank` for all your links. E.g.

```
$(function(){
  $("#myDiv a").attr("target","_blank");
});
```

[Example on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MfvZr/)

Comment: @ayush you can put the above code in document.ready...so that it will update all the a hrefs

Comment: @gov - Added the doc ready code. I just took it for granted. :)

Comment: Just a small question this will add target _blank to all links on the div and leave alone the ones that already have it right? It will not add it again if it already have target?

Answer (score 0):

You really ought to put them in.  If it's too time-consuming, try using a simple regex to do it for you (only run it on the html you care about).  Replace:

```
(<a href[^>]*)(>)
```

with

```
$1 target="_blank"$2
```

If you really need to, you can use JavaScript, but it won't work where javascript is disabled. It's really a terrible solution for this problem:

```
var el = document.getElementById('myDiv'); // or some other way of making `el` point to your element
var links = el.getElementsByTagName('a');
for( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ )
{
  links.target = '_blank';
}
```

Comment: links[i].target = '_blank';

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the Javascript that I use to set all the links within a certain div (or all links which are labeled with a certain class) to open in a new window: http://icode4you.net/use-javascript-to-open-all-links-within-a-certain-div-in-a-new-window.

I originally found this script at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex8/newwindow3.htm